# How to remove a row from a grouped pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like:

```
data = {'id':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 
         'var_1':[44, 20, 44, 50, 50, 44, 30, 44], 
         'var_2':[100, 120, 100, 80, 80, 100, 80, 100]}
```

df

```
   id  var_1  var_2
0   1     44    100
1   2     20    120
2   3     44    100
3   4     50     80
4   5     50     80
5   6     44    100
6   7     30     80
7   8     44    100
```

Then I grouped the data frame by two variables:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['var_1', 'var_2'])
```

Then inside a for loop each time I find a specific group, for example var1=44 and var2=100, that matches some searching criteria I have. For example:

```
current_group = df_grouped.get_group((44,100))
```

current_group

```
   id  var_1  var_2
0   1     44    100
2   3     44    100
5   6     44    100
7   8     44    100
```

How can I remove a row in this `current_group` in a way that the deleted row is dropped from `df_grouped` so it won't show up again in the next iteration.
Thank you

Comment: remove before groupby

Comment: I cannot. I have to group by first and then find that row, id=3 for example, within a specific group.

Comment: This hypothetical removal of `id=3` example does not appear to helping. It is not apparent with `id=3` why you would be able to remove it from the group, but not know it needed removed before the `groupby`. Now if your question was: how to remove the second element from _every_ group, or how to conditionally remove rows from group based on condition _x_ then that might be more understandable. Can you update your question to clarify under what circumstances rows need removed and why the groupby needs to occur before removal?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just edited a little bit and remove that ```id=3```. Hopefully that help making my question more clear now.